# Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon : Suddenly different look after update

Tags: linux-mint, gui, cinnamon, cursor

I am running Linux Mint Cinnamon on three different machines (and I am still quite new to the Linux world).
On two machines, the most recent update (current 21.2 version as of November 2023) worked fine (everything looks like before in the desired Mint style).
On one of the machines, there were "Flatpack" notices in the end of the update process (I do not remember the content, unfortunately) and after the update the mouse arrow suddenly looked like this

[image]

and not like this anymore

[image]

Also, other (graphical ) things changed. I don't know where to look for the source of this different behavior.

I have figured out that I can change most things back to the design as before using *Settings > Themes*. But it looks that for some reason I switched to a completely other "Mint branch".